# Add cell values in plotly heat map in r

Tags: r, plotly

Maybe is a silly task, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.
I just want to plot the cell values in the heat map using plotly

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotly)

data <- matrix(data=20, nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
data<- as.data.frame(data)
colnames(data) <- letters[1:10]
rownames(data) <- LETTERS[1:10]

pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd"))(29)
pal[1] <-c("#FFFFFF")


plot_ly(x = colnames(data), y = rownames(data), z = data, type = "heatmap", colors = pal, height=700, width=700, xgap=10, ygap=10, showscale=TRUE)
```

When I try `add_annotation` or setting  `layout` pad etc, it prints the values on the diagonal of the matrix...
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following code I generate the plot below.
I added the text using `add_annotations` on a reshaped dataframe.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

data <- matrix(data=rnorm(100), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
x <- letters[1:10]
y <- LETTERS[1:10]

df = data.frame(data)
colnames(df) = x
rownames(df) = y
df = df %>% 
  rownames_to_column("y") %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "y") %>% 
  mutate(value = paste0(round(value*100,2),"%"))

pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd"))(29)
pal[1] <-c("#FFFFFF")


plot_ly(
         z = data, 
         x = x,
         y = y,
         text = data,
        type = "heatmap",
        hoverinfo='none',
        colors = pal) %>% 
  add_annotations(
    data = df,
    x = ~variable, 
    y = ~y, 
    text = ~value, 
    xref = 'x', 
    yref = 'y', 
    showarrow = FALSE, 
    font=list(color='black'))
```

[image]

Comment: Prego! Could you select it as the answer then? :)